# Using different tables for authentication

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

So i have been developing a portal where there are three kind of users. `Students, University & Agent` . Each are signed up with completely different details as follows,

```
Students:
- first_name
- last_name
- email
- password

And University:
- Univ name
- rep name
- email
- country
- password

And Agent:
- Company name
- rep name
- email
- country
- password
```

So, how to handle this ? Should i need three separate tables and have separate login page to auth process ? Or is there a better approach ! ?

Sorry for the noob question, but couldnt find a effective way on dealing this

Comment: no use one and fill only the needed fields per type and of couese the type so that you only show the necessary gui parts

Comment: If so, we need to leave empty fields and also logically it doesnt sound right ? As a student table doenst need to have agent _name etc ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want them log in on the same page. Add another table that will handle privilege user account for log in so when user log in (don't forget to ad FK to others table), system will check privilege it has then route them base on that privilege.

Comment: Each user have different user fields, how will you add these in a single table ?

Comment: look @Gilbert Le Blanc has answer it. But he forget user id field on User

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a common User table with separate Student, University, and Agent tables.  The sign-in pages would be different, but the login page would consist of email and password.

```
User:
- email
- password
- account type

Student:
- first_name
- last_name
- User ID

University:
- Univ name
- rep name
- country
- User ID

Agent:
- Company name
- rep name
- country
- User ID
```